# Pikachoose gallery - incorporating fancybox

Tags: javascript, gallery, fancybox, image-gallery

I have images being displayed with pikachoose gallery, and the fancybox works perfectly to show the full size images when you click thumbnails, but I was wondering if it is possible to add arrows to go to the next image while viewing the full size image, you can see my work in progress here:

===old link that doesn't work anymore===

There's 2 javascript code snippets, the top one is for the pikachoose and the bottom for the fancybox, I am not too good with javascript, so I have no idea how to integrate both codes: the bottom example that I got from the fancybox site into my top pikachoose script to be able to click arrows to go next while viewing the full-size images.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call your fancybox from picachoose make a manual call providing the array of locations of all your pictures in the gallery. It should look something like that:

```
$.fancybox([{
            'href'  : 'img1.jpg',
            'title' : 'title1'
        },{
            'href'  : 'img2.jpg',
            'title' : 'title2'
        },...], ..here comes rest of fancybox setup..)
```

The only problem I see is to start with the right picture as I am not aware of the fancybox option to start viewing gallery with eg the third image in the set.

One solution would be to write the JS function which would return the array of images to display starting from the clicked one and wrapping back to the first in the set.

Comment: Alternatively, create the collection of objects on the fly http://stackoverflow.com/a/16047602/1055987