# Pikachoose API hook with Fancybox not working in IE9 or lower

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cross-browser, fancybox

So I've been currently testing out the Pikachoose gallery for API hooks and did have a gallery with three thumbnails working well. I've then added the API hook for when the animation finishes and runs a function to create a Fancy-box for one of those thumbnails.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
   var a = function(self){
      self.anchor.fancybox({
            'width'             : '60%',
            'height'            : '55%',
            'autoScale'         : true,
            'transitionIn'      : 'elastic',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none',
            'type'              : 'iframe' 
      });
   };
   $("#pikame").PikaChoose({animationFinished:a});
});
```

This works in Firefox, Chrome & Opera. It doesn't seem to work in IE9 or lower and in the interest of avoiding any page errors that may be lurking on my test site, I've created a jsfiddle (** [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GbwrH/)) and end up with the same result - animating once in thumbnail transition and then breaking

Anyone have some idea as to why IE 9 seems to break?

Comment: Don't know what you may be doing wrong but this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16047602/1055987 works fine with IE7+

Comment: Hi JFK, I've tried to follow your advice on the link you provided and it does work in IE at least the one I have here in jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/aXCF3/2/) but when you click the last thumbnail it breaks the fancybox when returning to first or second.

I'm looking to only have the fancybox enabled on the first image so I've avoided using any anchor tags around the third to test it working in just pikachoose only. Am I missing something so that it will still call the fancyGallery function after viewing an image without anchor tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When clicking on 2nd and 3rd images, PikaChoose's `finishAnimating` unwraps image from anchor and clears field `this.anchor` before calling `animationFinished`, so your `self.anchor` is `null` in ALL browsers (tested in Chrome, IE9, IE10). IE just makes this bug visible.

Comment: I see, sticking with JFK's method i've been able to fix the Pikachoose gallery to actually show the third image where as before it would allow the change of one image and then break.

With what you're saying the image that doesn't have an anchor tag doesn't use the function in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aXCF3/2/)?

Would you be able to suggest a way of ensuring that the code works out that any image in the pikachoose gallery with an anchor tag is always enabling an initialising a fancybox? ( even if it's just the first image in the gallery?)

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/aXCF3/4/ - fancybox is bound to clicking on big image no matter is it enclosed in anchor or not, and gallery information is extracted either from `href/title` of enclosing `a` (if it exists) or from `src/alt` of `img` itself

Comment: So essentially once your remove that bind of clicking on the big-image, with a static image chosen from the Pikachoose gallery it's unwrapped from fancyboxs' code and will no longer initialise the fancybox?

I am seeing other bugs in how i'm doing this with the pikachoose gallery breaking should I submit a form on the same page that posts to itself. What confuses me more though is the fact this working in all other browsers without so much as a problem.

Is there a way to disable a click on elements specified within the pikachoose gallery as a workaround?

Comment: I fear I'm not completely understood your comment. Do you want to completely remove `fancybox`? If so, then you should remove `fancyGallery` and `fancy` from script, and `buildFinished: fancy` from `PikaChoose`'s options. Or if you want to ignore clicks on thumbnails then look at http://jsfiddle.net/aXCF3/5/

Comment: Hi Victor, Sorry I wasn't clear (i'm still confused myself).

I just want fancybox to work on one image, the first image in the pikachoose gallery. I also need the gallery along with the fancybox to work in IE.