# Pikachoose fancybox always starts from first image of first gallary

Tags: jquery, fancybox, pikachoose

I am trying to build multiple galleries by using pikachoose+fancybox. Here is how the code looks.

```
var fancyGallery = [];
(function ($) {
  var fancy = function (self) {  
  self.anchor.on("click", function(e){
  var pikaindex = $(".pikame").find("li.active").index();
   $.fancybox(fancyGallery,{
    "cyclic": true, // optional
    "index": pikaindex
  });
   return false;
  }); // on click
 }
  $(".pikame").find("a").each(function(i){
  fancyGallery[i] = {"href" : this.href, "title" : this.title};
  }).end().PikaChoose({
  buildFinished: fancy,
  carousel:true
  });
})     (jQuery);
```

Obviously its going to start from the first image of the first gallery. anyway to get start from the particular image of gallery ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Looks good in the demo from where you got the code from http://stackoverflow.com/a/16047602/1055987

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pikachoose/Fancybox Integration - navigation arrows on the lightbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026145/pikachoose-fancybox-integration-navigation-arrows-on-the-lightbox)

Comment: Thanks @JFK for the quick reply. But the demo stands for a single gallery. But I am dealing with multiple galleries so its having multiple active <li> tags. any way to start with the right one image. ?

Comment: Do you mean that you have more than one pikachoose gallery? If so then I think you need to run `.each()` for each `.pikame` selector. BTW, what version of fancybox?

Comment: Yup, More than one galleries so multiple active li elements and its always going to return first one. I am using fancybox v2.x. will you please explain more :) Thanks :)

Comment: @JFK Any way to start with the particular galleries active image and navigate through whole gallery ? Or either create an separate array for separate galleries ? will you please give a idea ?